# How to add custom properties to Laravel paginate json response

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, response

I have the following simple index method:

```
public function index()
    {
       // dd(Poll::paginate(2));
      return response()->json(Poll::paginate(2),200);
    }
```

The output of that method is looks like the following json object:

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"title": "I suppose?' said Alice. 'Why, you don't know.",
"created_at": "2018-09-14 16:42:11",
"updated_at": "2018-09-14 16:42:11"
},
{
"id": 2,
"title": "Alice; but she knew that it seemed quite.",
"created_at": "2018-09-14 16:42:11",
"updated_at": "2018-09-14 16:42:11"
}
],
"first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls?page=1",
"from": 1,
"last_page": 6,
"last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls?page=6",
"next_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls?page=2",
"path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls",
"per_page": 2,
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": 2,
"total": 11
}
```

I want to add another array property after `"total: 11"` attribute such as:

```
,
"anotherData" : [
   "userId": 1,
   "userName": "john10",
   "message": "This is a message"
]
```

**I have tried** to understand how `response()->json()` works, so it can extract some data from `LengthAwarePaginator` object which it is the output of `Poll::paginate(2)` from [this resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#json-responses), but I could not able to understand how does it able to get an array from `LengthAwarePaginator` that holds the resultant keys in the json object?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the regarded [resource above](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#json-responses), the `json()` method takes an array and, I guess that, if the parameter is not an array, it tries to convert it to array, specially if it is an object like `LengthAwarePaginator`, so it may use `toArray()` method.

I have tried replacing `return response()->json(Poll::paginate(2),200)` with `return response()->json(Poll::paginate(2)->toArray,200)`, then I have got the same output. Hence, I have decided to replace the code of my index method to be like the following:

```
public function index()
    {
        //dd(Poll::paginate(2)->toArray());
        $output = Poll::paginate(2)->toArray();
        $output['userData'] = ['userId' => \Auth::user()->id, 'userEmail' => \Auth::user()->email];
        return response()->json($output,200);
    }
```

The resultant output is:

```
...
"path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls",
"per_page": 2,
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": 2,
"total": 11,
"userData": {
"userId": 1,
"userEmail": "lion@example.com"
}
}
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're directly responding with the paginated data, a better option would be to wrap it in a [Resource Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) and [adding meta data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data) to it.

This is how I implemented it.

**CategoryController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    return new CategoryCollection(Category::paginate(10));
}
```

**CategoryCollection.php**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'status' => 1,
        'message' => 'Success',
        'data' => $this->collection,
    ];
}
```

Since `Collection` extends `JsonResource`, your response would automatically be converted to JSON when returned from the Controller.